# Ehcache - java.io.EOFException for disk persistent cache for removeAll operation

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-cache, ehcache-3

We are using ehcache in our spring boot application.  Our spring boot version is 2.0.3.RELEASE and spring-boot-starter-cache 2.0.3.RELEASE uses ehcache 3.5.2.

Our motivation to use ehcache was that it is both jsr107 compliant and provides offheap support.

Below is our spring config:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerFactoryBean jCacheManagerFactoryBean() throws IOException {
        JCacheManagerFactoryBean jCacheManagerFactoryBean = new JCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        Resource resource = context.getResource("classpath:mts/ehcache.xml");
        jCacheManagerFactoryBean.setCacheManagerUri(resource.getURI());
        return jCacheManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheCacheManager ehCacheCacheManager() throws IOException {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty(Caching.JAVAX_CACHE_CACHING_PROVIDER, "org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider");
        JCacheCacheManager jCacheCacheManager = new JCacheCacheManager();
        jCacheCacheManager.setCacheManager(jCacheManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        jCacheCacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
        return jCacheCacheManager;

    }

}
```

The problem we face in production is, for a disk persistent cache with moderately big size, we have the below java.io.EOFException  error in removeAll operation :

```
Error : RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
        at org.terracotta.offheapstore.disk.storage.FileBackedStorageEngine$FileChunk.readKeyBuffer(FileBackedStorageEngine.java:541) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.terracotta.offheapstore.disk.storage.FileBackedStorageEngine.readKeyBuffer(FileBackedStorageEngine.java:265) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.terracotta.offheapstore.storage.PortabilityBasedStorageEngine.readKey(PortabilityBasedStorageEngine.java:119) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.terracotta.offheapstore.OffHeapHashMap$DirectEntry.<init>(OffHeapHashMap.java:1540) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.terracotta.offheapstore.OffHeapHashMap$EntryIterator.create(OffHeapHashMap.java:1518) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.terracotta.offheapstore.OffHeapHashMap$EntryIterator.create(OffHeapHashMap.java:1511) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.terracotta.offheapstore.OffHeapHashMap$HashIterator.next(OffHeapHashMap.java:1407) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.terracotta.offheapstore.AbstractLockedOffHeapHashMap$LockedEntryIterator.next(AbstractLockedOffHeapHashMap.java:399) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.terracotta.offheapstore.AbstractLockedOffHeapHashMap$LockedEntryIterator.next(AbstractLockedOffHeapHashMap.java:392) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.terracotta.offheapstore.concurrent.AbstractConcurrentOffHeapMap$AggregateIterator.next(AbstractConcurrentOffHeapMap.java:553) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.AbstractOffHeapStore$1.next(AbstractOffHeapStore.java:499) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.AbstractOffHeapStore$1.next(AbstractOffHeapStore.java:489) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheBase$Jsr107CacheBase.removeAll(EhcacheBase.java:708) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Cache.removeAll(Eh107Cache.java:304) ~[ehcache-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2 7941fa2573343b31ae56a12564404552c6d6eff0]
        at com.mycompany.myproject.services.cache.service.impl.CacheService.doClearCacheWithName(CacheService.java:56) ~[MyProjectServicesCache_classes.jar!/:?]
```

There is nothing special in the code calling the removeAll operation. Just gets the cache with name and calls clear all:

```
private void doClearCacheWithName(String cacheName) {
    Cache<Object, Object> cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
    if (cache == null) {
        throw new MyProjectException(String.format("Cache with name : %s does not exist!", cacheName));
    }
    logger.info(String.format("Clearing cache with name : %s", cacheName));
    cache.removeAll();
}
```

Here is the production config for ourBigCache:

```
<cache alias="ourBigCache">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">21600</ttl> 
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
            <disk unit="MB">4096</disk>
        </resources>
    </cache>
```

We could not reproduce this neither locally nor for test environment.

Please note that this cache has very a high usage (read count is very high in production), but I guess that should not make any difference .

I could not find any similar reported issue. There are  some very old disk problems menitoned but they are too old and not similar:

https://sourceforge.net/p/ehcache/discussion/322278/thread/e7a62df3/
http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/2694.page

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from my reply on ehcache-users:

> Most likely this is just another symptom of https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/2542 which was fixed in 74239a93e14eb7477841fffa36c971ef9e930686
>
> Unfortunately this fix hasn’t been merged anywhere yet. If you want to pick this up you could cut your own build of master (which would probably be a good thing to verify). Otherwise you'll have to wait for the first dot-release on the 3.7 line (timeline unknown at this point).
>
> Chris

Comment: thanx will try to apply your fix. Regards

Comment: For all those interested, the fix Chris mentioned seems to solve the problem. It has been a week in production without any error:)